# Move constructor bypasses copy constructor

Tags: c++, constructor

As expected the following does not compile:

```
class A {
public:
    A() = default;
    //A(A&&) = default;
    A(const A&) = delete;
    int x;
};

int main()
{
    auto a4 = A{}; // not ok, copy constructor is deleted
    auto a5 = A(); // not ok, copy constructor is deleted
    return 0;
}
```

But if a move constructor is added, even with the copy constructor explicitly deleted, then the following does compile:

```
class A {
public:
    A() = default;
    A(A&&) = default;
    A(const A&) = delete;
    int x;
};

int main()
{
    auto a4 = A{}; // now ok, even though copy constructor is deleted
    auto a5 = A(); // now ok, even though copy constructor is deleted
    return 0;
}
```

Why isn't the deleted copy constructor considered?

Comment: Because either `A{}` or `A()` produces a mutable non-const pure right value.

Comment: `auto a6 = a5;` would be an error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Why isn't the deleted copy constructor considered?

It *is* considered. It's just not used, so the fact that it's `delete`d doesn't matter. That rule, from [dcl.fct.def.delete] is:

> A program that refers to a deleted function implicitly or explicitly, other than to declare it, is ill-formed.
>   *[ Note:* [...] If a function
>   is overloaded, it is referenced only if the function is selected by overload resolution. [...] *—end note ]*

Overload resolution on `auto a = A{};` (braces vs parens is equivalent in this case) finds two constructor candidates:

```
A(const A&);
A(A&& );
```

One of the rules for choosing which candidate is the "best viable" candidate is, from [over.match.best]:

> Given these definitions, a viable function F1 is defined to be a better function than another viable function
>   F2 if [...], and then
>   — [...]
>   — the context is an initialization by conversion function for direct reference binding (13.3.1.6) of a reference
>   to function type, the return type of F1 is the same kind of reference (i.e. lvalue or rvalue) as the
>   reference being initialized, and the return type of F2 is not

The move constructor is the same kind of reference (rvalue) as the parameter, whereas the copy constructor is not. Hence it's preferred and selected as the best viable candidate. Since `A(const A&)` wasn't selected by overload resolution, we're not referring to that constructor, so the code is fine.

If we actually used the copy constructor on the other hand (e.g. `A a(a5)`), *that* would actually attempt to use the copy constructor, which would be ill-formed.

Comment: This answers it for me. That would also explain why it does not compile if I swap the `delete` and `default` on the two constructors. The overload resolution 'locks on' to the move constructor if it is there.